# Pods do not get installed to Pulsar namespace

Tags: bash, kubernetes-helm, minikube, pulsar

I am currently attempting to install Pulsar onto a Minikube cluster using Helm. Everything does seem to install correctly, but the pods do not get registered under the correct namespace. I am running the following script to install Pulsar onto Minikube:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this script assumes that the pre-requisites have been
# installed, and that you just need to create a minikube
# cluster and then deploy pulsar to it

# startup a minikube kubernetes cluster
minikube start --memory=8192 --cpus=4 --kubernetes-version=v1.19.0

# point kubectl towards minikube
kubectl config use-context minikube

# install the pulsar helm chart
./pulsar-helm-chart/scripts/pulsar/prepare_helm_release.sh --create-namespace --namespace pulsar --release pulsar-mini

# install pulsar using the helm chart
helm install --set initialize=true --values pulsar-helm-chart/examples/values-minikube.yaml pulsar-mini apache/pulsar

# wait and then show what is going on
sleep 1m
kubectl get all

# need to wait or else the pods wont display
sleep 5m

# display the pods
kubectl get pods -n pulsar -o name
```

Instead, the Pods show up under the default namespace. Running the query to get pods under the Pulsar namespace yields the following:

```
xyz-MacBook-Pro:pulsar xyz$ kubectl get pods -n pulsar -o name
xyz-MacBook-Pro:pulsar xyz$
```

Whereas, I am able to see all of the installed Pods when doing a generic query for all pods:

```
xyz-MacBook-Pro:pulsar xyz$ kubectl get pods -o name
pod/mysite-769d76764c-6dnct
pod/pulsar-mini-bookie-0
pod/pulsar-mini-bookie-init-xbnsc
pod/pulsar-mini-broker-0
pod/pulsar-mini-grafana-555cf54cf-wdcs5
pod/pulsar-mini-prometheus-5556dbb8b8-s7q2d
pod/pulsar-mini-proxy-0
pod/pulsar-mini-pulsar-init-sq87h
pod/pulsar-mini-pulsar-manager-6c6889dff-ckfwl
pod/pulsar-mini-toolset-0
pod/pulsar-mini-zookeeper-0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `-n pulsar` to specify the namespace when you use the `helm install` command.

Comment: Let me give that a try, and I will get back to you.

Comment: This worked, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The default namespace for the Apache Pulsar charts should be "pulsar, so there might be an issue/change in the the version you are using. However, you can specify the namespace using the `--set namespace=<name>` option in the `helm install` command

Therefore your command should look like this:

`# install pulsar using the helm chart helm install --set initialize=true -set namespace=pulsar --values pulsar-helm-chart/examples/values-minikube.yaml pulsar-mini apache/pulsar`